# Debug AIR Application on Client Machine

Tags: debugging, air

I have an AIR application that is causing me problems on a single client machine, and on a specific user account.

I have a debug interface that I developed to print traces to but apparently you can not get stack traces when not in a debugging environment.

I am seeing "TypeError #2007" with no additional information. I tried to output the error text using e.getStackTrace() and it returns null.

How can I get more information about this error on a client machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance I was able to isolate the problem using a bunch of different try..catch statements and a lot of trace statements.

It took a lot of persistence and a lot of back and forth installing many different versions on the client machine and testing.

Obviously not an optimal solution in most cases, but one that worked.